# WebView justify text not correct on Galaxy Nexus

Tags: android, webview

My application use webview to display contect which I parse from website.
The problem happen when user use my app on galaxy nexus(may be cause 1280*720 resolution)

my  tag is just simple use text-align:justify;. 
and here is my webview config

```
    WebView web = (WebView) root.findViewById(R.id.webView);                
    web.loadDataWithBaseURL(null,content, "text/html", "utf-8",null);
    web.getSettings().setUseWideViewPort(true);
    web.getSettings().setLoadWithOverviewMode(true);
    web.getSettings().setBuiltInZoomControls(true);
```

here is my xml layout for webview

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:ads="http://schemas.android.com/apk/lib/com.google.ads"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" android:id="@id/root" android:gravity="center_horizontal">

    <WebView
        android:id="@+id/webView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1" >
    </WebView>

    <com.google.ads.AdView
        android:id="@+id/ad"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        ads:adSize="BANNER"
        ads:adUnitId="a14fd0c4bb5aa9f"
        ads:background="@drawable/bg_main_repeat"
        ads:primaryTextColor="#FFFFFF"
        ads:secondaryTextColor="#CCCCCC" />

</LinearLayout>
```

I test my app on Sony Xperia P(Android 2.3) no problem found. and test on emulator 4.0 with 800*480 no problem found too.

my problem show in : http://images.droidsans.com/sites/default/files/Screenshot_2012-06-14-21-53-11.png
user need to double tap to zoom the text fit screen.

what should i do? please help me

PS. sorry for my poor English. I'm not a native speaker.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try to use this :

```
WebView.loadData("<head><style>* {margin:0;padding:0;font-size:15; text-align:justify}</style></head>" + "your data", "text/html", "UTF-8");
```